# Uploading and loading images through jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp-classic

So, let me explain it better, I'm pretty sure the title doesn't says much.

I'm in charge of doing some improvements on the company system. Now the system saves the current image, as a file, and insert into the database the path of the image.

Then, what's the problem if it works? Well, if the server gets a lot of images being inserted all the time, the server will need some improvements, so my first thought was, why don't I save the image data to the database and load it through ajax call? That's nice, it won't make the server overload from lots of gigabytes from the images, won't have problems with duplicates and such, but when I call the ajax method from jQuery, the data sent to the server side is via query string and if the data is higher than 6000 characters, like most are when I use base64 encoding, I can't call the method.

My other thought was, send the image to the server side and then generate the data to save to the database, and when the user wants to see the image, the server transform the data to an image and sends to the client side. But the problem is, there are lots of users for this system, and sending/receiving lots of images will make the server get memory problems due to the high amount of requisitions.

So to make long story short, what is the best way to send/receive images from client to server and the opposite without overloading the server capacity.

P.S.: Sorry for the long post, I wanted to make a clear question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: images in the database are almost always a bad idea, and sending everything out as base64 will boost your bandwidth bill by ~33%. Store the images in the file system and just store the image's PATH in the database, then you can load them trivially with a standard `<img>` tag.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the fast answer, and second, do you think it's worth to compress the images when I save on the server-side to reduce the amount of space on the hard-drive? It's a 24/7 system that constantly exchange images between server/client, so it will overload a bit the server, I guess.

Comment: @MarcB: an imporant addition would be to note that images should NOT be saved directly in the physical folder of the web application. Rather, you save them to a separate share and expose through an url facade, possibly handled by a separate server. If done properly, this increases security and performance.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I quite did not understand what you meant by "you save them to a separate share and expose though an url facade". You mean I'll load the image to another web server and from there I save the image on a separated directory, and when I want to load, I load it using the web server? I'm not an expert on this web area, so please don't get mad. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server will overload even more storing the images in the DB. Most web servers serve static files (like images) very efficiently.

You have to think more about the problem before trying to solve it:

- **Is your problem bandwidth overload?** Try resizing the images client side before upload (you can use tools like PlUpload). If you can't, at least resize them server side to serve them smaller and save on download bandwidth
- **Is your problem harddrive space overload?** Again, resize the images client o server side.
- **Is your problem CPU overload?** Try to determine the root code that is the cause of the spikes. Be aware that lots of requests will cause high CPU, and you might need a more beefy server (or another webserver)

Comment: Well, my problem is a high amount of image traffic between server and client. When I upload an image, it will store the image on a folder using a web server and will insert the path into the database. So every time the user request the image, I will load the path from the database and then get the correct image from the folder to send to the client. But imagine if, for 10 minutes, 500 clients do the same request over and over because of some panic. It will overload the database with requests and will overload the server with image traffic. That's why I was thinking about rendering client side.

Comment: Since I couldn't finish my comment, I appreciate your answer, I will use a web server to administrate the images and insert the path on the database. It's more useful to the client to have a fast website for him than make the client suffer from lots of rendering and such. Thanks, you opened my mind. And sorry to not Up-vote you, I still don't have enough reputation.

Comment: You can use caching to avoid hitting the DB so hard. About the requests, you can use a CDN, but maybe it's an overkill